# Use result of sql query to replace text on multiple xml files

Tags: sql-server, xml, replace, notepad++

i have a table on sql like this:

```
CD_MATERIAL | CD_IDENTIFICACAO
1           | 002323
2           | 00322234
...         | ...
```

AND SO ON (5000+ lines)

I need to use that info to search and replace multiple external xml files on a folder (all the  tags on those XML had numbers like the CD_IDENTIFICACAO from sql query, i need to replace with corresponding cd_material from sql query "ex.: 002323 becomes 1)
I used this query to extract all the cd_identificacao to use on Notepad++:

```
declare @result varchar(max)
select @result = COALESCE(@result + '', '') + CONCAT('(',CD_IDENTIFICACAO,')|') from TBL_MATERIAIS WHERE CD_IDENTIFICACAO <> '' ORDER BY CD_MATERIAL
select @result
```

That would bring me ex.:

(1TEC45D025)|(1TEC800039)|(999999999)|(542251)|(2TEC58426)|(234852)

and changed the parameters to get the replace ex.:

(? 2000)|(? 2001)|(? 2002)|(? 2003)|(? 2004)|(? 2005)

but i don't know how to add a number (increment) on front of "?" so notepad++ would understand it (search and replace would have 5000+ results, so it's not pratical to manually add the increment).

Comment: This is extremely unclear.  It's hard to even know what to ask you to clarify... are the XML files in the database?  You need to provide much more detail if you want help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get a workaround for this. I've used this query to get all the the terms for find and replace i needed (1 per line)

```
select concat('<cProd>',cd_identificacao,'</cProd>'), concat('<cProd>',cd_material,'</cProd>') from tbl_materiais where cd_identificacao <> '' order by cd_material
```

That would result in:

```
<cProd>1TEC460054</cProd>   <cProd>1</cProd>
<cProd>1TEC240035</cProd>   <cProd>2</cProd>
```

(i added the tag too to make sure no other information could be replaced as there were many number combinations that could lead to incorrect replacement)

then pasted it on a txt and i used the notepad++ to replace the space between column 1 and 2 for /r/n wich would result in:

```
<cProd>1TEC460054</cProd>
<cProd>1</cProd>
<cProd>1TEC240035</cProd>
<cProd>2</cProd>
```

then i used "Ecobyte Replace Text" Tool, pasted my result file as new selection in bottom frame, loaded all my files on a new replace group on top frame (on properties of the group, u can change directory and options), then executed the replacement, it worked perfectly.

Thx.